# AngularJS: Hide divs when dropdown is unselected, and output text

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm still new to AngularJS, and I've tried looking for the solution to my problem but I can't seem to find one that specifically addresses this. Sorry if this has been asked before! And by new, I mean, I'm still pretty clueless on how much of this works.

I have an array of items that I'm displaying with ng-repeat. Each item has a drop down where they can select Yes or No, or leave it unselected. The data is sorted so that anything that's set to Yes or No moves to the top of the list.

I currently also have a checkbox that allows them to Hide an item, which hides it, and moves it to the end of the array, so that it doesn't clutter them up.

I would like to instead have a button that hides all unselected items (a value of neither Yes nor No), instead of making them hide one at a time.

Second: Any item where they've selected Yes should have their names displayed in Field One; Any items where they've selected No should have their names displayed in Field Two.

Here is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('List', []);
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

$scope.selected = false;

$scope.pList = [
    {
              id: '1',
              title: 'Apples',
              checked: false
          },
        {
            id: '2',
            title: 'Oranges',
            checked: false
        },
        {
            id: '3',
            title: 'Bananas',
            checked: false
        },
        {
            id: '3',
            title: 'Pears',
            checked: false
        }
];

$scope.pStatus = [
 {
    stat: 'Unselected',
    color: 'black'
},
{
    stat: 'Yes',
    color: 'green',

},
{
    stat: 'No',
    color: 'red'
}
];
```

}]);

```
<div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card" ng-repeat="stuff in pList |  orderBy: ['checked', 'selectedpStatus', 'id']:false">
            <div ng-hide="stuff.checked">
                <h2 class="title">{{ stuff.title }}</h2>
                <br /><br /><br />
                <div class="status" ng-style="{'color':stuff.pStatus.color}">
                    <select ng-model="stuff.selectedpStatus" ng-options="item.stat for item in pStatus"></select>

                </div>
                <p class="normal">Hide <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="stuff.checked" id="{{ stuff.id }}" /></label></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <div class="main">
            Field One: :{{ stuff.title }}:
            <br />
            Field Two:  :{{ stuff.title }}

        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

There are several questions/clarifications I'd typically want to ask, but here's an answer that should guide you further:

1. Have a property on the scope that stores whether the filter should be applied or not.
2. You can then filter the array using a `filter` in the controller, or defined globally. Or, just hide the elements you don't want shown using an `ng-if` directive on each element.
3. The logic for showing the title in field 1 vs 2 is simple; the issue is whether you do this for all items, or if you want to somehow select one to show outside of the repeat.

Here's a basic solution though:

```
  <button type="button" ng-click="toggle()">Hide/Show Unselected</button><br>
  Hide all: {{ hideAll }}<br />

  <div class="card" ng-repeat="stuff in pList |  orderBy: ['checked', 'selectedpStatus', 'id']:false"
    ng-if="!hideAll || !stuff.selectedpStatus || stuff.selectedpStatus.stat !== 'Unselected'">
    <div ng-hide="stuff.checked">
      <h2 class="title">{{ stuff.title }}</h2>
      <div class="status" ng-style="{'color':stuff.pStatus.color}">
        <select ng-model="stuff.selectedpStatus" ng-options="item.stat for item in pStatus"></select>
      </div>
      stuff.selectedpStatus: {{ stuff.selectedpStatus }}<br>
      Field One: {{ stuff.selectedpStatus && stuff.selectedpStatus.stat === 'Yes'  ? stuff.title : '' }}<br />
      Field Two: {{ stuff.selectedpStatus && stuff.selectedpStatus.stat === 'No'  ? stuff.title : '' }}<br />
    </div>
  </div>
```

and

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.selected = false;
  $scope.hideAll = false;

  $scope.pList = [{
    id: '1',
    title: 'Apples',
    checked: false 
  }, {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Oranges',
    checked: false
  }, {
    id: '3',
    title: 'Bananas',
    checked: false
  }, {
    id: '3',
    title: 'Pears',
    checked: false
  }];

  $scope.pStatus = [{
    stat: 'Unselected',
    color: 'black'
  }, {
    stat: 'Yes',
    color: 'green',

  }, {
    stat: 'No',
    color: 'red'
  }];

  $scope.toggle = function() {
    $scope.hideAll = !$scope.hideAll; 
  }

});
```

In a plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/PBr753nznrMwsgAIsTwE?p=preview

Comment: That's great! It hides everything I want to hide and shows everything I want to show. Thank you so much!

To answer the clarification: I want the pList.title to show in an outside field, and have all of the ones that were set to Yes be in that field. Something like, Yes: "Apples, Bananas". No: "Oranges, Pears".

Comment: In other words, I can get it to show {{ pList.title }} inside the div, and individually, but I'd like to have a field where all of the "Yes" selection's titles are displayed.